# When trying to compile magic file : Warning: type `' invalid and Warning: offset `search' invalid

Tags: files, compiling

I'm trying to compile a very basic magic file with the command:

```
$ file -C -m foo
```

I get this error:

```
foo, 1: Warning: type `' invalid
foo, 2: Warning: offset `search' invalid
foo, 3: Warning: type `' invalid
foo, 4: Warning: offset `Itis42file' invalid
```

My file looks like this:

```
42
search
42
Itis42file
```

I have followed the man magic and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the `magic` file is described in the `magic(5)` manual on your system (`man 5 magic`).

On an Ubuntu system I have access to (as well as on my OpenBSD system), the format is described as a collection of lines with the following fields:

```
offset type test message
```

I'm guessing that your file should therefore not contain four lines, but one:

```
42 search 42 Itis42file
```

This does indeed work on OpenBSD:

```
$ cat ~/.magic
42 search 42 Itis42file
```

```
$ cat file.txt
                                            42 hello
```

```
$ file file.txt
file.txt: Itis42file
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot, but why would my setup won't compile it then ? I am using zsh unix on a mac

Comment: @Ilan Have you tried again with a properly formatted magic file?

Comment: do you mean on the same line ? and not on different lines ? ill try in about 1-2hrs ill let you know

Comment: @Ilan Yes exactly, that's the main issue with your magic file.